# Control in for loop in Django template

Tags: python, django

I don't know a lot about Django or Python, but I know it's problematic using a simple for loop in a template.

I'm wanting to do the following and wondering my options are - is there a simple way to do this in the template?

```
{% for image in my_images %}  //only loop through 1-10
```

Then:

```
{% for image in my_images %}  //only loop through 10-20
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `my_images` is a list, you are looking for [the `slice` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#slice):

> ```
> {{ some_list|slice:":2" }}
> ```
>
> If some_list is `['a', 'b', 'c']`, the output will be `['a', 'b']`.

Of course, on an optimization note, it would generally be better to do this at a view level by not fetching more records than you need.

Comment: right, and {{ some_list|slice:"2:6" }} for subsets.  Wierd that's ok but for loops aren't..Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you need all the data but want to display it in chunks, you can split up your list like this

```
def Chunks(l, n):
    return [l[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(l), n)]
```

where n=any number, in your case it would be 10

Then all you need to do is loop through the chunked list in the template.

Comment: That's a really ugly way to chunk, check the [`itertools` `grouper()` recipe](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) which works on arbitrary iterables, not just lists, and does so without looping by index.

Comment: Thanks will definitely have a look at those.